# Triangle inequality in ML inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Show that $\left|\int_C \frac{1}{z^2+1}\le\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}\right|$, where $C$ is the straight line segment from $z=2$ to $z=2+i$.

The contour length here is 1, so all we have to worry about is the M's value to get ML. We have to maximise the thing so we have to minimise the denominator using triangle inequality.

but when I do it, the answer is not matching with what I have to prove.

|z^2+1|≥||z^2|-1|

and since we need the minimum value we use z=2.

so 4-1 = 3.

I am getting 1/3, but the answer I have to prove is different.

Comment: You need better estimation for function (you need to consider domain for this), $|z^2 + 1| \geq |z|^2 - 1$ is too imprecise for this case.

Comment: Try parameterizing $z$ and write $\left|z^2+1\right|$ as a product of two terms. Can you continue from there?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. I have [edit]ed your question to reflect this principle.

Answer (score 1):

The length is (obviously) $1$ by the Distance Formula:
$$
L = \sqrt{(2-2)^2 + (1-0)^2} = 1.
$$

On $C$, parameterize $z(t) = 2+t(2+i-2) = 2+it$ where $t \in [0,1]$.

A nice way to minimize $\left|z^2+1\right|$ is by

$$
\left|z^{2}+1\right|=\left|z-i\right|\left|z+i\right|=\left|2+it-i\right|\left|2+it+i\right|=\sqrt{t^{2}-2t+5}\sqrt{t^{2}+2t+5}.
$$

We can employ the First Derivative Test for both expressions. For the first one,

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\sqrt{t^{2}-2t+5}=\frac{t-1}{\sqrt{t^{2}-2t+5}}.
$$

The only critical number we really need is $t=1$. Then we plug in the infimum and supremum of the domain of $t$ like

$$
\sqrt{0^{2}-2\left(0\right)+5}=\sqrt{5} \text{ and } \sqrt{1^{2}-2\left(1\right)+5}=2.
$$

Hence, $\min\left\{\sqrt{t^2-2t+5}\right\} = 2$.

Do the same for the other expression to get $\min\left\{\sqrt{t^2+2t+5}\right\} = \sqrt{5}$.

Thus,

$$
|f(z)| = \left|\frac{1}{z^2+1}\right| \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}.
$$

We conclude with

$$
\left|\int_C f(z)dz\right| \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}} \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}.
$$

Comment: +1 nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1** For two complex numbers $z$ and $w$ (with $|z+w|>0$), we have $$\dfrac{1}{|z+w|}\le\dfrac{1}{||z|-|w||}.\tag{1}$$

**Hint 2** Split $C$ into two straight line segments: $C_1$ from $2$ to the midpoint $m=2+i/2$ and $C_2$ from $m$ to $2+i$.

**Added.** For $z_1=x_1+iy_1\in C_1$, we have $|z_1|>2 $ and for $z_2=x_2+iy_2\in C_2$, we have $|z_2|>\frac{\sqrt{17}}{2} $.
Now use $(1)$, for $w=1,z=z_1^2$:

$$\frac{1}{|z_1^2+1|} \le \frac{1}{||z_1^2|-1 |}=\frac{1}{||z_1|^2-1| |}\le \frac{1}{3},\tag{2}$$

and similarly to $$\frac{1}{|z_2^2+1|} \le\frac{4}{13}.\tag{3}$$
Finally, apply ML inequality to each integral (with $L=1/2$): $$\left|\int_{C_1} \frac{1}{z_1^2+1}\right|\le\frac{1}{6} \qquad\text{   and    }\qquad\left|\int_{C_2}  \frac{1}{z_2^2+1}\right|\le\frac{2}{13}.\tag{4}$$

Hence $$\left|\int_{C} \frac{1}{z^2+1}\right|\le\frac{1}{6}+\frac{2}{3}\le\frac{1}{2\sqrt{5}}.\tag{5}$$

Comment: How did you get $|z| \geq 4$?

Comment: @Accelerator my bad, thanks for pointing out my mistake.